# How do you insert an image into a Python program?

Tags: python, macos, image

I'm trying to insert an image into a Python program, but I just can't figure out how to link the image to code so I can view it once the code is run. I am new to python, I have version 3.9.7 on a Mac computer.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can give me a hand in solving the problem.

Greetings, Gaia.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on *inserting an image into a python program*? If you find to add an image and work with it then you can take a look at [pillow library](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pillow-a-fork-of-pil/). Another option is [opencv](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/opencv-python-tutorial/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use OpenCV for this
https://learnopencv.com/read-display-and-write-an-image-using-opencv/

You need to install the library first, running the following command on your terminal `pip install opencv-python`

```
# import the cv2 library
import cv2

# The function cv2.imread() is used to read an image.
img_grayscale = cv2.imread('test.jpg',0)

# The function cv2.imshow() is used to display an image in a window.
cv2.imshow('graycsale image',img_grayscale)

# waitKey() waits for a key press to close the window and 0 specifies indefinite loop
cv2.waitKey(0)

# cv2.destroyAllWindows() simply destroys all the windows we created.
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# The function cv2.imwrite() is used to write an image.
cv2.imwrite('grayscale.jpg',img_grayscale)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use theses modules:

[opencv-python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/opencv-python-tutorial/):

```
import cv2
```

[Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```
from PIL import Image
```

[scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/)

```
import skimage
```